# MVC controller gives me a 403 forbidden error with the default route when it's called DocumentationController

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is `DocumentationController` reserved for system usage or something?

I created a blank MVC app, created a DocumentationController with corresponding view. It works if I go to `www.mysite.com/Documentation/Index` but if I go to `www.mysite.com/Documentation/` then I get a 403 forbidden.

Renaming `DocumentationController` to `Documentation2Controller` and associated views, it (the default route, etc.) works perfectly.

Is it a reserved keyword or could there be another reason why it doesn't pick up the default route?

Comment: Did you make sure you don't have an actual virtual/physical directory named 'Documentation'?

Comment: Oh man. You totally solved it. Gold star. Can you post that as an answer? There's a folder in the solution called Documentation and after renaming that, it fixed it. I don't see why that should affect it since it should be looking in Views>MyControllerName>Index but it did.

Comment: There could be a better way to handle this. Please show your `RoutesConfig`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make sure you don't have an actual virtual/physical directory named `Documentation`.

You can also instruct MVC to 'take over' the request even when it matches a directory by setting the `RouteExistingFiles` flag to true (in your Routes configuration):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Top advice. The RoutesConfig is just the default one, I hadn't changed it. I simply didn't realise it would conflict with folders that have the same name as the controller. Much appreciated.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer helped me! ''Make sure you don't have an actual directory named...'' In Visual Studio, I clicked the icon to ''Show All Files'' and realised there is a folder with the same name. (created during runtime since I made a mistake in defining the right directory for it) Clicking Show All Files, revealed it. I deleted it and everything went back to normal..

Comment: Wow, the RouteExistingFiles = true was missing from my RouteConfig.cs. Now it's working!

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem using this word as controller name. (At least in ASP.NET MVC3)

The only reserve words are these:
http://bitquabit.com/post/zombie-operating-systems-and-aspnet-mvc/