# Default route when using ASP.NET MVC attribute routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I'm using attribute routing with Web API, and everything works as expected if I request the URL **/myapi/list** with the following controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("myapi")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("list")]
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
       // Return result
    }
}
```

However, I would like my **Get()** method to be the **default**, i.e. when requesting the URL **/myapi** (without the **/list** part).

But if I remove the **"list"** part of the **Route** attribute like so...

```
[RoutePrefix("myapi")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route] // Default route
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
       // Return result
    }
}
```

...I get a **403.14** error saying

> "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this
>   directory."

Any ideas of what might be causing this?

Thanks!

**Edit:** If I request the API controller using the default route pattern like **/api/myapi**, it maps to the **Get()** method as expected.

Default route is registered after the attribute routes:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a physical/virtual directory named `myapi`?

Comment: @haim770 Hmm, indeed, that seems to be the problem! If I rename my route prefix, the default route works as expected! Thanks so much for your help! Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: It just reminded me of http://stackoverflow.com/a/24533925/1625737 - Not sure whether it's qualifies as duplicate though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [haim770](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625737/haim770) in the comments: the problem was that I had a **physical folder** with the **same name** as the route prefix.

Renaming either the folder or the route prefix solved the problem.

I guess an alternative would have been to tweak the route/handler order to ensure attribute routes take precedence over physical paths.

Comment: Another possible solution is to use `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true`, as mentioned in the answer I linked to

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
[Route("")]
```

for the default route

```
[RoutePrefix("myapi")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    //GET myapi
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] // Default route
    public async Task<string> Get() { ... }
}
```

Reference: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2 : Route Prefixes](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes)

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi, but I seem to be missing an attribute called **Default**?

Comment: That was a typo. sorry

Comment: Ah, ok! :) I tried with both **""** and **"~/"** as arguments for the **Route** attribute, but it yields the same result. :/

Comment: The above code will work. if it doesn't then the problem exists outside of the controller. which URL do you want `/myapi` or `api/myapi` you have both in the question?

Comment: I want it *without* the prefix, so just **/myapi**.

Comment: It seems the problem stemmed from a physical directory with the same name as the route prefix. :/ Thanks for your help, though!