# How to set up default route in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having troubles understanding the default route setup in MVC5. I have this code in the RouteConfig.cs file

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Content",
        url: "content/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When I go to `www.mydomain.com/content/index` it works fine. However if I go to `www.mydomain/content` I get an error 403.14 Forbidden. I understand this is a newbie question but what am I missing? Should it not default to the index controller?

Comment: Do you have a physical content folder on the site? I used to get that issue because I had a matching physical root folder that matched a controller.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24533925/1625737

Comment: @haim770 you should add that as the answer because it does provide a solution for the OP. I had overlooked that option as a possible solution.

Comment: @Nkosi, If it does actually answer the question, then the entire post is duplicate. And although setting `RouteExistingFiles` to `true` will work, I don't think it's the way to go.

Comment: @haim770, understood and agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using default Asp.Net MVC5 project template then there already exists a physical folder called content in the project and by extension, the root of the site.

If you try to browse to the content folder IIS will give you that error. The request would not reach the route table.

Consider renaming either the folder or the controller. Each would have their own knock on effect depending on the requirements of your project.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be something right in front of me but I did not think about the default content folder.

Answer (score 0):

go to project **properties** select **web** tab change specific page