# IIS trying to browse directory for an empty route attribute

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I have created an api controller with attribute routing:

```
[RoutePrefix("fonts")]
public class InfoController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSomeInfo()
    {
        return Ok(new { Name = "Some name" });
    }
}
```

And I have a folder in the project root called "fonts".

when I am trying to request:

```
GET /fonts
```

IIS throws an error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

How can I fix this to call the controller action?

**UPDATE:**
Here is the web api config class, which is the default web api configuration created by VS.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is attribute routing enabled?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question to show the web api configuration.

Comment: Yes, that solved the issue

Comment: While it works there may be knock on issue if the web api is mixed project with plain MVC. Why have both the physical folder and the controller?

Comment: Yes it is mixed but it's kind of having exactly the same folder structure for controllers because of better organizing the project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is solved in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24533925/87514).

I had to set:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Comment: This option has nothing to do with ApiControllers, but rather MVC controllers.