# The simplest example with MVC attribute routing doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I use VS2013 and created MVC application by wizard. I also deleted all extra files and have the following:

1) RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

2) HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("Home/Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

3) Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

Home page
```

I've got the page with error:

```
HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden
```

But, if I add to URL in browser's address bar manually - Home/Index:

```
http://localhost:50600/Home/Index
```

The page appears.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What URL do you use when it fails

Comment: I put "Home/Index" in Route attribute on Index action.

Comment: I understand that. What is the problem? That is not clear.

Comment: I've already written - when I run the application I've got the page with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "Home" from the route as the controller name `HomeController` is already starting your route with "Home". If you want to change that "Home" prefix, you can add an attribute to the HomeController class to define that.

Also, the default route name for an action will match the action name, so in this case you could use `[Route("")]` and the url /Home/Index would work.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that for sure, but I think it's because of the blending of attribute based routing and standard routing. I've bumped into this many times. If you fully define everything as attribute based routing it will work. If you fully define everything the standard way it will work. When you blend the two you get cases like this, most commonly on the default routes.

Comment: I removed all what refers to old routing style with routing tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's your problem now. You're expecting the default url to show up your `Index` View in `HomeController` but you've not setup the default route. You can set the default route by adding the following lines in your RouteConfig.cs

```
config.Routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Alternatively, if you wish to use attribute routing only without mixing with route template, you can just add the default route as following:-

```
config.Routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Index",
    url: "",
    defaults : new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: What's the url that showing error? I believe it's different with what you request as you're able to load it without problem. It would be helpful if you let us know how you invoke the error url or show us the web request via Chrome inspector.

Comment: @tesicg Updated my answer after identified the underlying issue.

Comment: I don't want to use old mapping routes style. All should work with attribute routes.

Comment: @tesicg Perhaps this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533643/mvc-controller-gives-me-a-403-forbidden-error-with-the-default-route-when-its-c. Basically you have a folder called Home in the root of your website project and that conflicts with your Home folder under controllers.

Comment: @tesicg Then all you need is specifying the default route as in my 2nd solution. You still need to specify the default route as basically it just add the default route into the RouteTable entries without all the matching complexities of routing engine.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you try this url:

http://localhost:50600

It does not work because you have removed the default route from your routes config. I don't know if you removed it yourself, but RoutesConfig.cs file usually comes with the following default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This code ensures that if the user does not provide the controller or the action the site will default to index action of the home controller (you ca see that under the defaults parameter). This would also explain why it works when you try this route:

http://localhost:50600/Home/Index.

Comment: I've returned back that standard block of code and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Did you rebuild the project? If yes, do you have any other controller titled "HomeController" in the project? The default route should be the very last line in your RegisterRoutes method in RouteConfig.

Comment: No, I don't have any other controller. That's the simplest MVC application.